# Is it possible to reverse perspective projection with simple scale and translate?

Tags: 2d, 3d, perspective

Basically I'm asking this question (which seems to have gone un-answered): [How to do perspective projection “parallax” but without changing the scale or offset of objects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48257/how-to-do-perspective-projection-parallax-but-without-changing-the-scale-or-of)

I'm using perspective projection and would like to scale up certain objects in the background (z < 0) such that they would render unscaled and in the same relative position. In other words, I want to reverse the perspective foreshortening for bg objects.

I've figured out how to unscale accurately: basically I project the top left and bottom right corners of the image to z = 0, then do the same at the current z value. I then compare the change in distance between the points in order to derive the scale factor.

The problem I have though is once I unscale the object, its position is incorrect. I've tried scaling around different anchor points, with no luck. I can't seem to derive a generic formula to position the images in the correct places after scaling.

Any ideas how to do this? Is this even mathematically possible?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll suggest an edit to the other post